# Why does VB.NET exit this Regex Thread? "The thread has exited with code 0"

Tags: .net, regex

I have a substring that may or may not exist in a larger string, and if it does it should contain some contact information that I want to grab with a regular expression.

Due to message parameters beyond my control, this substring may sometimes be truncated, so I've written a couple different regular expressions to accommodate for each scenario.

The problem I'm running into is that the more complicated expressions die on me.  These expressions have run just fine on every Regex testing website that I've tried.

Here's a code clip for reference.

```
' Look for contact information using regular expressions.  Data we're looking for is in the format below
' "-- Contact: [name] [email] [phone]"
Dim ContactPattern As String
Dim ContactMatch As Match

If SomeStuff Then
' Only look for the [name] block
ContactPattern = "((?:-- Contact: \[)((\w*|\W*|\s*|\S*)*)\])"
' This match attempt works fine.
ContactMatch = Regex.Match(FullString, ContactPattern, RegexOptions.None)

' Do stuff with the results

ElseIf SomeOtherStuff Then
' Look for [name] and [email]
ContactPattern = "((?:-- Contact: \[)((\w*|\W*|\s*|\S*)*)\] \[((\w*|\W*|\s*|\S*)*)\])"
' This match attempt does not get processed.  I receive the message below in the output window.
'The thread '<No Name>' (0x1f58) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
ContactMatch = Regex.Match(FullString, ContactPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

' Do stuff with the results

ElseIf SomeOtherOtherStuff Then
' Look for [name] [email] and [phone]
ContactPattern = "((?:-- Contact: \[)((\w*|\W*|\s*|\S*)*)\] \[((\w*|\W*|\s*|\S*)*)\] \[((\w*|\W*|\s*|\S*)*)\])"
' This match attempt does not get processed.  I receive the message below in the output window.
' "The thread '<No Name>' (0x1f58) has exited with code 0 (0x0)."
ContactMatch = Regex.Match(FullString, ContactPattern, RegexOptions.None)

' Do stuff with the results

End If
```

Unfortunately Google has failed me (or I've failed it).  Does anyone have any thoughts?  Again, the regular expressions themselves evaluate successfully on Regex test sites.

Comment: Just something to note; your question does not actually involve VS2010, even though that's what you are programming in. vb.net, regex, and perhaps .net are the appropriate tags here. the vs2010 tag would be for an issue with the tooling, extensions, and usage of vs2010 itself.

Comment: Noted, and tag removed to avoid false positives when others search.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have probably encountered [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). Your regexes contain nested repetitions of patterns that are not mutually exclusive. Especially `(\w*|\W*|\s*|\S*)*` does not make any sense. `\w` and `\W` in combination contain **all** characters. So do `\s` and `\S`. Also the inner asterisks do not accomplish anything, because the outer repetition can take care of that as well.

If, what you want to accomplish, really is to match **any** character there, you can simply replace every `(\w*|\W*|\s*|\S*)*` by `[\s\S]*`. Alternatively `.*` in combination with `RegexOptions.Singleline` does the same.

Comment: `[\s\S]*` still matches any character

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It that is what I said. I just suggested how to get rid of the catastrophic backtracking while keeping semantics.

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It if you use `RegexOptions.Singleline`, yes

Comment: @m.buettner - Good call.  I've had very little experience with Regular Expressions, so this was very helpful.  As an FYI, I ended up using the following pattern for the full match portion to make it a little more specific (capture any character except the closing ]).
'(((?:-- Contact: \[)(([^\]])*)\] \[)(([^\]])*)\] \[(([^\]])*)\])'